# matlab saving a cellarray

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a script which does not fully work:

inputfield=input('Which field would you like to see: ','s')

if isfield(package, inputfield)

```
 fprintf('The value of the %s field is: %c\n',inputfield,...
 eval(['package.' inputfield]))
```

else
     fprintf('Error: %s is not valid field\n', inputfield)

end

First I define a structure in matlab and then i use the script on the structure:

> > package=struct('item_no',123,'cost',19.99,'price',39.95,'code','g')

package =

```
item_no: 123
   cost: 19.9900
  price: 39.9500
   code: 'g'
```

> > structurevalue
> >     Which field would you like to see: cost

inputfield =

cost

The value of the cost field is: 1.999000e+001

> > structurevalue
> >     Which field would you like to see: item_no

inputfield =

item_no

The value of the item_no field is: {

> > 

why cant it read value for item_no?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
fprintf('The value of the %s field is: %s\n',inputfield,...
    num2str(package.(inputfield)))
```

There were two issues with your version.

1. You were passing both numbers and strings into the `%c` field in your `fprintf` string. When a decimal goes in, it is interpreted as a number and displayed in full precision, which is why 19.99 got displayed as 1.999000e+001. But when an integer goes in, it gets interpreted as a character, which is why 123 got displayed as '{' (ASCII character 123). Use `num2str` to convert numbers to strings for display. Also, use `%s` for a string of any length, rather than `%c` for a character.
2. In general, it's not a good idea to use `eval` unless you have to. In this case, it's more convenient to use `inputfield` as a [dynamic field name](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html#br1v5cc-1) of `package`.